# Is addIceCandidate implemented in Dartium?

Tags: dart, dartium

I'm trying to call:

peerConn.addIceCandidate (where peerConn is an instance of RtcPeerConnection)

and I'm getting:

NotSupportedError: Internal Dartium Exception

Is addIceCandidate supported? And what is the status of WebRTC in Dartium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a issue on the Dart bug tracker regarding this problem:

> [Issue 15008 - RtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate results in a NotSupportedError: Internal Dartium Exception](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15008)

It seems that (at the moment) the only workaround is to use dart2js with Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

The newest Versions (bleeding edge) seem to fix this problem. You can download them right [here](http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/be/raw/latest/).