# How to call addIceCandidate in dart

Tags: exception, dart, webrtc, dartium

I want to connect two peers with RTCPeerConnections but I am not able to add the IceCandidate from Alice to Bob.

example:

```dart
var alice = new RtcPeerConnection(
   {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}
);

var bob = new RtcPeerConnection(
    {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}
);

alice.createDataChannel("somelablel", {});

alice.onNegotiationNeeded.listen((var data){
    alice.createOffer({}).then((var offer){
        //got offer
        alice.setLocalDescription(offer);
        bob.setRemoteDescription(offer);
    }); 
});

bob.onIceCandidate.listen((evt) {
    if (evt.candidate)
        print(evt.cancelable);
    });

alice.onIceCandidate.listen((evt) {
    if(evt.candidate != null)
        //TODO: add iceCandidate to Bob
});
```

**First version (seems to be old but is heavily used in online examples):**

```dart
bob.addIceCandidate(candidatefromAlice);
```

Output:

```
Class 'RtcPeerConnection' has no instance method 
'addIceCandidate' with matching arguments.
```

**Second try (new version with 3 parameters):**

```dart
bob.addIceCandidate(candidatefromAlice, (){}, (var error){
    print(error.toString());
});
```

Output:

```
NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the 
requested type of object or operation. (Dartium)
```

How can I set the ICE candidates in dart without problems?

Info:

> Dart VM version: 0.1.2.0_r30864 (Wed Dec  4 11:03:45 2013) on "linux_x64"
>   dartium : Chromium 31.0.1650.48

Comment: The Dartium version is not very helpful. Better are the version information in Darteditor>Help>About menu or the output from ```dart --version```

Comment: Could you please provide more code. What is ```bobsRtcPeerConnection``` and what is ```candidatefromAlice```?

Comment: I added some context.

Comment: Isn't this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896137/is-addicecandidate-implemented-in-dartium the same question with an referenced code example?

Comment: I got the same error with an older version. This error seems to be different (at least the exceptions are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by using the js-interop library. Just use proxies:

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

// ...

_rpc = new js.Proxy(js.context.webkitRTCPeerConnection, js.map(iceServers));

// ...

var iceCandidate = new js.Proxy(js.context.RTCIceCandidate, 
        js.context.JSON.parse(/*your icecandidate string*/)
      );

_rpc.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to wait until this bug is fixed
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15008

the code you are asking for seems to be

```dart
bob.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate, () => print('void: $evt'), (var x) => print('FailureCallback: $evt'));
```

A comment on this question [Is addIceCandidate implemented in Dartium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896137/is-addicecandidate-implemented-in-dartium) seems to indicate that it doesn't work in Dartium but works in Chrome after converting the project to JavaScript.

Comment: it seems to be similar, but different error. I get *"NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation. (Dartium)"* and not *"NotSupportedError: Internal Dartium Exception"*